# Scala REPL class loader returns 'null' when calling getResourceAsStream() method

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Why does Scala REPL's `TheReplClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(someGeneratedClassName)` return null?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the resource named `someGeneratedClassName` does not exist? Java will return `null` [if the resource cannot be located](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very detailed. Are you using the standalone REPL or instantiating an interpreter? In the latter case, you may find some useful information about the interpreter's class path in this mailing list post : http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8002

Answer (score 1):

No reason other than it being in the "not yet implemented" category.  It does now.

```
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/24624
```